# Desktop is laggy after installiny Nvidia Drivers 19.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, video

I recently upgraded from an AMD Raedon 590 RX to a Nvidia 2070 RTX. Nvidia Driver version is 418.56

Although my mouse cursor itself isn't lagging (144hz refresh rate), I am noticing that if I draw a box on my desktop, there is some input lag from moving the mouse to seeing the box get created.

Also in ALL videos and audio, it takes a couple seconds for VLC player, a youtube video, or spotify to load the content. My internet connection is fine and for example, with youtube, my video will take a couple seconds to load, then play with no sound for a couple seconds before finally working.

When I pause the video, the issue repeats itself. This also happens in VLC player too.

My main monitor is hooked up with a display port cord, and my speakers are going through the monitor as well (wasn't able to connect speakers directly to computer, it refused any input other than my two shitty monitor speakers).

I believe the problem has to do with the Nvidia driver situation, but what can I do more to trouble shoot and figure out whats going on?

Comment: I've noticed horrible window resizing lag on 4K monitor I've never seen on 2K monitors before. What resolution are you running at?

Comment: 1920 x 1080. I have a dual monitor setup, both of them are at 1920 x 1080. The 144hz monitor is connected via display port and my speaker runs into it. The other one is 60hz and connected via HDMI